# Which sequence is $a_n=\gcd(50+n^2,50+(n+1)^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let be the sequence $b_n=50+n^2$, for $n=1,2,3...$ . Which is the sequence $a_n=\gcd(b_n,b_{n+1})$?

The first values are $3,1,1,3,1,1,3...$, so I think that is the series. I've tried writing $n$ as $3k+1, 3k+2, 3k$ but I'm not able to prove it.

Comment: $\gcd(50+33^2,50+34^2)=67$

Comment: I found this counterexample almost at the same time. $201$ can also occur , for example for $n=100$

Comment: Interesting is whether those $4$ values are all that can occur. I remember a similar gcd-expression which is $1$ upto a huge counterexample.

Comment: Note that $50+n^2=(2n+1)(\frac12n-\frac14)+\frac{\color{red}{201}}4$, and the factors of $201$ are $1, 3, 67$, and $201$

Comment: Did you mean $b_n$ where you wrote $b_1$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Wow, that's it since the gcd must divide $2n+1$. Nice !

Comment: $a_n = \gcd(n-100,201)$ by the formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3308853/242) in the linked dupe. The rest is easy.

Comment: the difference between an index where b is 67 or 201 and the previous index, where b is 67 or 201 seems to be always 67 (at least until n<10^6)